# inserting multiple rows with varying data with one query

Tags: sql

So .. I want to have a query that creates multiple rows with one query. Say I want something like this

```
Row 1: col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2', col3 = 'val3'
Row 2: col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2', col3 = 'val4'
Row 2: col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2', col3 = 'val5'
```

where

```
val3,val4,val5
```

are returned by a sub-query. I was thinking something like

```
insert into  table_name (col1, col2, col3) values ('val1', val2, (select column_name from table_two where condition));
```

Any ideas how I can do this with one query?

Comment: Are 'val1' and 'val2' always the same for every row? Are they in a separate table?

Comment: Yes. They are supposed to be the same for every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible: if your `val1` and `val2` are constant, then:

```
insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3) select 'val1', 'val2', column_name from table_two where condition;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT
    'val1', 'val2', column_name 
FROM table_two 
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
insert into  table_name (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 'val1','val2',column_name 
from table_two 
where condition
```

Have a look at [SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  However, instead of using the keyword values, select constants.  Something like this.

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2, field3)
select 'fred', 'barney', SomeField
from table1
where whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT FROM` - have a look at this link [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-the-insert-statement-in-sql-server/)